# Parse XML in SQL Server 2016

Tags: xml, sql-server-2016

I need guidance on why I am receiving two null values as "result" instead of receiving "approved" text?

```
DECLARE @xml XML

SET @xml = '<Process>
                <DataArea>      
                    <UserArea>
                        <Property>
                            <ChildProperty name="Decision" type="StringType">Approved</ChildProperty>
                        </Property>
                        <Property>
                            <ChildProperty name="somethingelse" type="StringType">somethingelsevalue</ChildProperty>
                        </Property>
                    </UserArea>
                </DataArea> 
            </Process>' 

SELECT
    b.value('(/ChildProperty[@name="Decision"]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS result
FROM   
    @xml.nodes('/Process/DataArea/UserArea/Property') AS a(b)
```

Comment: XML support is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @marc_s updated title.

Comment: @marc_s updated tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close - you just have to make sure *not* to select from the root again in the expression that evaluates the `ChildProperty`.

Change your code to this:

```
SELECT
    b.value('(ChildProperty[@name="Decision"]/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS result
FROM   
    @xml.nodes('/Process/DataArea/UserArea/Property') AS a(b)
```

You had this:

```
b.value('(/ChildProperty[@name="Decision"]/
```

Note the `/` before the `ChildProperty` - this starts the search at the root. You need to search *within the context* you're in - so I removed that leading forward slash in my sample.

Comment: thanks, it worked. thank you for clarifying the "/" behavior.